# Why UIButton is unresponsive?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` on top of every other views, pushing the next screen, but it's unresponsive to tapping.

Debugging, I have noticed that the User Interaction is ON but also OFF. I mean:

When I select the button at the view hierarchy) it says is ON.
When I select the button directly at the storyboard, it says is OFF.

[image]

Take a look at the image above.

Also, the outlets are connected and the call is correct:

`code`

```
@IBAction public func onFrontPressed(_ sender: UIButton)  {
    let destination = OnboardingAViewController(nibName: "OnboardingAViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
}
```

Does anyone knows what's going on here?

Comment: The image you shared doesn't have a picture of the storyboard, they're both the view hierarchy. And the right side has an ImageView selected.

Comment: add print in onFrontPressed ... to check ... its its getting called

Answer (score -1):

Solved!

There was 1 fully transparent gradient view above the button.

When I deleted it, everything was working again.

Thanks, community!